# How to map existed domain and existed Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cname

We have a site with domain: ***abc.com*** and a Google Cloud Storage bucket name ***data***
Follow tutorial at Google: [Hosting a Static Website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website), the domain and bucket must have same name !
How can I config to map domain with bucket have difference name ?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the only option for accomplishing this is by using Google Cloud Load Balancer and adding a GCS bucket to content-based load balancing. See instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/adding-a-backend-bucket-to-content-based-load-balancing

Another option might be to move or copy your data to a bucket named www.abc.com.